# Разметка 2 child div внутри 1 parent div. (отвыкаю от таблиц)

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[image]

Привет гуру, не пиннайте, помогите правильно разметить div'aми. Ума не приложу, пробовал конечно же float: left, float: right, display: inline. всё перекособочино. Буду премного благобдарен.

Comment: Вы уже задавали подобный вопрос — неужели не можете поиграться с флоатами? Попереставлять блоки и посмотреть, что будет? Учите элементарные основы ХТМЛ и ЦСС, а не генерируйте дилетантские вопросы по каждой мелочи. Вопросу — минус.

Comment: И не нужно начинать вопросы с подлизывания — не надо вот эти «привет гуру». И обращение, кстати, отделяется запятыми. И «не пиннайте» пишется так — «не пинайте».

Comment: Игрался что получается: по итогу парент див "не раздвигается по height"... Поэтому и сделал иллюстрацию и задал вопрос

Comment: Да, для того, чтобы родительский div, в котором есть float-элементы, сохранял нормальную высоту, нужно знать основы CSS — например, класс .clearfix или параметр overflow:hidden;

Comment: Кроме float`a на дивах можно сымитировать таблицу - display: table. Чем не вариант?

Можно так же попробовать position: absolute ([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/HTc4a/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-child"></div>
  <div class="last-child"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.first-child {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: blue;
}

.last-child {
  height: 100px;

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbnuz)

Answer (score 0):

http://csstemplater.com/ думаю там сделаете все, что вам нужно